# Inability to render domain class object as JSON in grails 3.3.8

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

***Hello, I am facing some serious challenges after updating my version of Grails from 3.2.4 to 3.3.8 and GORM to 6.1.10***

One example is rendering a domain class object or list of domain class objects as JSON

***Previously, the following would work but it fails after the update***

From my understanding, after updating, `domainObject.properties` doesn't return only a map of persistent attributes and their values, but other sub-objects and attributes that cannot be formatted as JSON, leading to the errors.

```
def action() {
    List<User> users = User.list(max: 10)
    render users as JSON
}
```

Therefore, my question is, is there a way to walk around this issue so that I can render objects as JSON without using `collect` to transform them?

Comment: The title is very misleading.  You can in fact render domain class objects as JSON in 3.3.8.  Also, "attributes that cannot be formatted as JSON" isn't clear.  All attributes can be formatted as JSON.  It would be helpful if you described a simple relationship and the desired corresponding JSON.  With that, a suggestion can be made for how to achieve the desired output.

Comment: Have you tried using [Grails Views][1]?


  [1]: http://views.grails.org/latest/